# One of my games

Tags: strategy

I played black.
The game was over in two hours.
I would like anyone's opinion on my game.

```
 [Event "Let's Play!"]
 [Site " Chess.com"]
 [Date "Jun 19, 2017"]
 [White "PATELAKSHAY"]
 [Black "JoshuaFischer007"]
 [Result "1-0"]
 [WhiteElo "1354"]
 [BlackElo "793"]
 [TimeControl "1 in 1 day"]
 [Termination "PATELAKSHAY won by checkmate"]
 [FEN ""]

 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 d6 4. dxe5 dxe5 5. Nc3 Qxd1+ 6. Nxd1 Be6 7. a3 O-O-O 8. Ng5 Rd7 9. Bb5 a6 10. Nxe6 fxe6 11. Bc4 Nd4 12. Ne3 b5 13. Bb3 Nxb3 14. cxb3 Nf6 15. f3 Rd3 16. b4 c5 17. Bd2 cxb4 18. axb4 Bxb4 19. Bxb4 Rxe3+ 20. Kf2 Rb3 21. Bc3 b4 22. Bxe5 Rf8 23. Rxa6 Ng4+ 24. Kg3 Kb7 25. Rxe6 Nxe5 26. Rxe5 Rxb2 27. Re7+ Kb6 28. Rxg7 b3 29. e5 Re2 30. Rb1 b2 31. e6 Re8 32. e7 Rb8 33. Rf7 Ka5 34. Rf8 Rb3 35. e8=Q Rxe8 36. Rxe8 Kb4 37. Rb8+ Kc3 38. Rxb3+ Kxb3 39. f4 Kc2 40. Rxb2+ Kxb2 41. f5 Kc3 42. f6 Kd4 43. f7 Ke5 44. f8=Q Ke6 45. Kf4 Kd5 46. Qe8 Kd6 47. Ke4 Kc5 48. Qd8 Kc4 49. Qd4+ Kb5 50. Kd5 Ka5 51. Kc5 Ka6 52. Qb4 Ka7 53. Kc6 Ka8 54. Qb7#  1-0
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I understand what you mean here. You want us to judge you as a player and point out your mistakes. You seek improvement by posting this game and want some expert comments.

True, you must try posting questions which are more specific, and should relate to a particular chess idea or position, or else explanations get cringe-worthy, and become offbeat, but I do not see any problem in posting the entire game here.

Anyways lets discuss the game and frame bullet points.

- Your 7th move should have been f6 or h6 and not castle. You should have preserved your bishop instead of the knight.
- I did not understand the move, 8) Rd7. You must try developing your minor pieces quickly.
- 17th move c*b4 is a blunder. The b4-pawn can wait to be taken. You are opening up the queenside, and making his rook active. A better plan would have been to wait and play Be7 and then doubling up rooks on e-file. You should have navigated the knight to Q-side for attacking the weak pawns. Nd7-Nb6-Na4/Nc4.
- At move 23rd R*a6 from white you are practically over.

My Summary is black should have shown some patience, and not attacked every move. There is a chapter called maintaining the tension, which I believe you must watch on YouTube, and which will give you great benefits. You should attack where you are strong. You had the Centre e-file, and suddenly you opened up the Q-side.

This game from Black is somewhat a 1300-1350 Elo rated Player .

Comment: Thanks, @Seth Projnabrata! I shall keep your advice in mind, it was useful!

Comment: Great . Please vote me up.

Comment: I did, but the site said that votes cast by those with reputation less than 15 are not displayed. Thanks anyway, I'll focus on ironing out my flaws!

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's no question that there's no question.

Even if your question was "can I have someone's opinion about my game," it would not be appropriate for StackExchange as questions should not be "primarily opinion-based," nor "with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer."

Questions like this are better:

- "What is the point of 5. Nc3, or is it purely a mistake?"
- "What defensive technique should I have employed in the double rook endgame?"

Comment: Agreed. If you want some advice on a game, *especially if you want to improve at strategy*, at least put in the effort to briefly describe the thoughts behind your moves (excluding very obvious ones) so that we can properly assess where you might have gone wrong. Did you have a coherent plan or did you make stuff up as you went along? That's important to know for useful advice.

Comment: ... is there irony here, in that your answer is also not an answer?